# External content type throws error while save

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

External content type throws error.

Following is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You want to fix the first, the second or both?

Answer (score 0):

For the first error message, check what operations you defined a step earlier:
[image]

For the second one, check permissions: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683113.aspx

Please check out also [this post from Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21c5ba47-e4b1-4402-b4ff-bea05cf7fd26/external-content-types-set-object-permissions-ribbon-button-disabled?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).